# How do I store mutilple checkbox values in local storage with javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, storage, local

Trying to store the value of the checkboxes but nothing seems to pop up on my local storage application for chrome :(

```
<label id='interest'>Interests:</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="education" value="education" name="user_interest"><label class="light" for="Education">Educational purpose</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="CCA" value="CCA" name="user_interest">
<label class="light" for="CCA">CCA Points</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="development" value="development" name="user_interest"><label class="light" for="development">Development</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="design" value="design" name="user_interest"><label class="light" for="design">Design</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="business" value="business" name="user_interest"><label class="light" for="business">Business</label>


<button type="submit" onClick="signup()" id="sign_up">Sign Up</button>




<script>
function signup()
{
localStorage.setItem("users_interests" + document.getElementByClassName("light").value, document.getElementByClassName("light").value);
}

</script>
```

Comment: There is no such method of the document called `getElementByClassName` only `getElementsByClassName` which returns a node collection, please see documentation here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function signup()
{
var users_interests =[];
var els = document.getElementsByName("user_interest");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {   
      if (el.type == "checkbox" && el.checked) { 
         users_interests.push(el.value); 
      }
    // Do stuff here 
});

localStorage.setItem("users_interests",JSON.stringify(users_interests));
  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users_interests")));
}
```

Comment: In this example we all checked and put the result into an array, if you want to use the comma-separated return, just remove the json.
json return array example - [a, b, c]
not json (string) example - a, b, c

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method of the document called `getElementByClassName` only `getElementsByClassName` which returns a node collection,, so you would need to change your function to something like this:

```
function signup()
{
    //Declare constant variable to hold the elements with class light
    const lightEles = document.getElementsByClassName("light");

    //Declare an array to hold the values
    let eleValues = [];

    //Iterate the node collection and push each element's value into the array
    for(let x = 0; x < lightEles.length; x++){
        eleValues.push(lightEles[x].value);
    }

    //Set array to localStorage key
    localStorage.setItem("users_interests", eleValues);
}
```